# Why axios async is different from fetch?

Tags: axios, fetch

This works:

```js
let buyTicketData = await fetch(`${baseURL}buyTicket`, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(postData),
  });

let buyTicketData2 = await buyTicketData.json();
```

this does not:

```js
let buyTicketData = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "buyTicket",
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
```

Why?

Got this error:

```
TypeError: buyTicketData.json is not a function
```

Same base URL is used: `http://localhost:3000/api/`

I have a reverse proxy, maybe that interferes?

Comment: Because it's a different API. Why would they have to be the same; why did you think an Axios call returned an object with a json method? (Assuming that's what you mean, given that you don't appear to be showing the line that errors.) Did you read [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema)?

Comment: @János In the `fetch` example, `buyTicketData` is a bad name. Call it `ticketdataResponse` or similar. In the axios example, `buyTicketData` is a bad name. Call it `ticketData`. You don't need to use `.json()` when you use axios because Axios decodes the response body for you.

Comment: ahh, yes, now I see, thanks @jonrsharpe, I need to wrap up like this: `const { data } = await axios({` and then this: `buyTicketData: data.data ?? null,`